# Error: install mglearn

Tags: python, pip, installation, conda

I have used "pip install mglearn" and "conda install mglearn". 
But it shows me the following error:

```
Solving environment: failed
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - mglearn
Current channels:
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
  ...
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
```

I have "Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)"

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python/issues/71

```
conda install pip 
pip install mglearn
```

In fact, I had an Anaconda ipython3 shell open and ran those commands without needing to restart the shell.

Answer (score 2):

You can download mglearn project from [its official github repository](https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python) and copy **mglearn** folder to

```
Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried using `pip install mglearn` and it worked for me. While `conda install mglearn` is not working due to unknown reasons.

Comment: This worked for me: https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python/issues/71  conda install pip
pip install mglearn

Answer (score 1):

try typing `pip install mglearn` in conda prompt,it worked for me.

Comment: Whilst your contribution as a new user is appreciated, I note that your suggestion has already been covered by some of the previous answers. Perhaps it would be better to try to assist with questions that are more recent and/or haven't been answered yet?

Comment: But that answer solved the problem in the easiest way mentioned. Or am I wrong and there are other implications using pip inside conda environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo pip3 install mglearn` instead of `pip install mglearn` in your terminal. It is important to replace `pip` with `pip3` for Python 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

People who want to use mglearn using a new environment for their projects in PyCharm (Selecting the option to create a new environment in PyCharm when creating a new project).
After the installation of mglearn using the command pip install mglearn in Anaconda environment (Anaconda3\lib\site-packages), you need to copy the folder mglearn to your new environment (Anaconda3\envs\"Your Project"\Lib\site-packages). It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Restart your system and try again.**
I have also faced a similar sort of problem. For the very first time, I found some errors in my terminal. Then I restarted my pc and again entered the same command and this time it worked perfectly. So, I think you should have tried two or three times at least before entering into any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jupyter notebook an easiest way to install mglearn is by entering this:

```
!pip install mglearn
```

And then import the module by usual way:

```
import mglearn
```

this worked for me:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you get mglearn issue about memory and "caching" then :

if have pyhton 3.12, joblib 1.2 and scikit-learn 1.2.2,

replace by python 3.10, joblib 1.1.1 and scikt-learn 1.1.0

respectively with :

pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip install scikit-learn==1.1
pip uninstall joblib
pip install joblib==1.1.1

to check :
pip list

Answer (score 0):

On Google Colab, you simply need to do the following:

```
!pip install scikit-learn==1.1
```

This will uninstall version 1.2, which has an ethical issue with the dataset required by mglearn.

```
!pip install mglearn
```

And it works!